# Why was this post deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, deleted-answers

I'm asking this question mostly out of curiosity. I'm not questioning anyone's authority.
[This answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/52466/19989) to one of my questions was deleted (sorry if not everyone can see it. The mods can and this question is mostly for mods).
I also see that the user that posted the answer does not exist anymore.
Either it was deleted or destroyed completely.
So I am asking why?
I know it may not be the best answer, but the question has such a nature that makes it impossible to provide an exact answer.
I think it had some good pointers in it.
It also contained a harmless joke. I think this is not a reason to delete an account.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree that being a "harmless joke" is not a reason to delete an account.

Being a sockpuppet of a suspended user, however, *is* a reason to delete an account, and that's what happened.

Comment: ah. that makes sense. Thanks for clearing it.